# How to actually use delta feed support with OData

Tags: c#, odata

There is a section in the documentation that describes using a "Delta Feed" feature of O-Data ([here](http://odata.github.io/WebApi/#04-13-DeltaFeed_support)). However, it does not appear to be complete and it is not at all clear how to use this feature in Web API OData. Specific questions are below.

In the OData spec you need to respond to the header Pref: odata.track-changes with a odata.deltaLink on the last page. This is used to retrieve the delta feed at a later date. How do you configure a controller method to support this? How do you stop other controller methods from allowing this? How do you populate the odata.deltaLink value in the response?

In the example provided, the change entity set it manually built based on static values and is part of the "standard" get controller method. How do you define a controller method that would be responsible for retrieving the delta feed separate from the "standard" get method? I would guess that we could use a special ODataRoute attribute. But that seems like it is a hack. How can you get the $DeltaToken value in the controller so you can do something with it?

The feeling I am left with from the documentation and the associated tests in the OData project is that there isn't really support for the OData spec's Delta Feed functionality. However, I think it might just be a lack of documentation?

Comment: HI, get ou any response or help with this? I have similar problem :)